# TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row, SQL Case Syntax error?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, oracle-dbms

I am receiving this error when using an insert cursor in ArcPy.

I have identified the cause of it as a syntax error, however have not figured out the correct syntax to resolve the error.

I am using a CASE statement to convert a boolean data type to a string.

The statement works in Management studio, however there is something clearly wrong with the Python syntax which is causing the error.

I am converting the `isproject` from SQL Server to Oracle SDE.

The `date` conversion works fine; however the conversion for `isproject` is not working as expected.

When I debug `fieldnames_string` this is the output for the `isproject`

`CASE WHEN [isproject]=1 THEN 'TRUE' WHEN [isproject]=0 THEN 'FALSE' END`

What needs to be changed in this SQL statement to to avoid this error?

```
import arcpy
import datetime
fieldnames = [field.name for field in descrip.fields if field.name != descrip.OIDFieldName]

        #workaround for dates conversion
        fieldnames_wrapped = []
        for fieldname in fieldnames:

            if 'date' in fieldname:
                fieldnames_wrapped.append('CONVERT(VARCHAR, {0})'.format(fieldname))

            if 'isproject' in fieldname:
               fieldnames_wrapped.append("CASE WHEN [isproject]=1 THEN 'TRUE' " +\
                                       "WHEN [isproject]=0 THEN 'FALSE' END".format(fieldname))

            else:
                fieldnames_wrapped.append(fieldname)
                fieldnames_string = ','.join(fieldnames_wrapped)


        # execute sql to get all new/updated tickets
        ticket_sql = "select {0} from {1} where {2} in ({3})".format(fieldnames_string, self.ticket_table_name, self.ticket_id_field, job_id_string)
        self.logger.debug(ticket_sql)

        conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(self.korterra_sde_path)
        results = conn.execute(ticket_sql)

        if results is None:
            raise Exception('Ticket query unsuccessful')
        elif results == True:
            # no results were returned
            raise Exception('Ticket query returned no results')

        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(ticket_table, fieldnames) as cursor:
            for result in results:
                # remove empty strings because of date conversion error
                row = [value if isinstance(value, basestring) and len(value.strip()) != 0 else None for value in result]
                cursor.insertRow(tuple(row))

        return ticket_table
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to include which DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL string has a .format(), but not a place to input it. ...unless "[isproject]" is really "{0}" in your code and you were trying to make it legible.

The following is what is giving you the syntax error:

```
        if 'isproject' in fieldname:
           fieldnames_wrapped.append("CASE WHEN [isproject]=1 THEN 'TRUE' " +\
                                   "WHEN [isproject]=0 THEN 'FALSE' END".format(fieldname))
```